# Generate high speed data using GTX transceiver of Kintex-7 FPGA board

Tags: fpga, transceiver, kintex-series-fpga

I want to use [Genesys-2](https://store.digilentinc.com/genesys-2-kintex-7-fpga-development-board/) FPGA board as a BER tester for transceiver circuits. I am using IBERT IP core available in Vivado for it. Genesys-2 has an FMC connector to provide output for which I am using [SMA-FMC-LVDS](http://www.hitechglobal.com/FMCModules/FMC_SMA_LVDS.htm)  of Hightech Global to convert the data from FMC to SMA. Initially, I am connecting transmitter and receiver in loopback just for verification.

The problem is:
1. In loopback connection, in Vivado I am unable to see any transmission. It is only displaying 0Gbps.
2. Previously I have used different [SMA-FMC](http://www.hitechglobal.com/FMCModules/FMC_SMA.htm) board for which transmission was proper and I was able to measure the BER. By this, it is clear that there is no problem with the code.
3. In the [SMA-FMC-LVDS](http://www.hitechglobal.com/FMCModules/FMC_SMA_LVDS.htm) a place holder is provided for an external oscillator. Do I need to solder this oscillator for proper transmission?

I can not find any supporting document for the configuration of [SMA-FMC-LVDS](http://www.hitechglobal.com/FMCModules/FMC_SMA_LVDS.htm).

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the working board (my emphasis):

> Reference clock for the serial transceivers of the carrier board is provided through the **module's super clock**  as well as a pair of SMA connectors for external pulse generators.

From the description of the non-working board:

> Reference clocks for serial transceivers are provided through 2 pairs
>   of SMA connectors and **external clock generator**.

My reading of that is that you do not have a reference clock when using the SMA-FMC-LVDS board, and that's why nothing is working. You can add an oscillator on board (as you say) - it has to meet very tight jitter specifications if I remember right. Or you can inject (again a good low-jitter) clock onto the FMC connectors provided for that clock.